# CouchbaseClient configuration for more than one cluster

Tags: couchbase

Let's assume I have two couchbase clusters with XDCR setup and having following nodes:

```
n1.cluster1.com
n2.cluster1.com
n3.cluster1.com
```

and

```
n1.cluster2.com
n2.cluster2.com
n3.cluster2.com
```

What is preferable node configuration for CouchbaseClient?

As from http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-sdk-java-1.4/#hello-couchbase

> The CouchbaseClient class accepts a list of URIs that point to nodes in the cluster. If your cluster has more than one node, Couchbase strongly recommends that you add at least two or three URIs to the list. The list does not have to contain all nodes in the cluster, but you do need to provide a few nodes so that during the initial connection phase your client can connect to the cluster even if one or more nodes fail.
>   After the initial connection, the client automatically fetches cluster configuration and keeps it up-to-date, even when the cluster topology changes. This means that you do not need to change your application configuration at all when you add nodes to your cluster or when nodes fail. Also make sure you use a URI in this format: `http://[YOUR-NODE]:8091/pools`. If you provide only the IP address, your client will fail to connect. We call this initial URI the bootstrap URI.

Does it mean I should add at least two or three nodes from each cluster? Or two or three node from the whole system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each `CouchbaseClient` object will only connect to one cluster. The list of node URIs should all belong to the same cluster - you'll likely get strange behaviour if you list nodes from different clusters.

If your application wants to connect to two different cluster (irrespective of if they have a replication stream between them or not), then you want to create two `CouchbaseClient` objects, one connected to each cluster.

Comment: So what does XDCR give me then? What if one cluster is down?

Comment: I would ask what your use case is that you need this functionality. Using Couchbase as normal, you get HA functionality with replicas, failover, etc. XDCR would be used to replicate for purposes of creating a reporting DB, backups, Geo HA, etc.

You would need application logic that if the local cluster is unresponsive in X time, you create a new CouchbaseClient object to the second cluster. Just be aware of Couchbase's current style of conflict resolution between two separate clusters.

Comment: Agreed, and I would add that using any software outside of its design intent will undoubtedly result in unexpected (and in this case, probably bad) behavior.

Comment: Cluster itself gives you HA for your application (no need multiple clusters to achieve HA). XDCR is meant for disaster recovery and geographically (in terms of network latency/load) distant deployments.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend adding all nodes of the cluster to your client connect configuration. The reason is that if one or more of the nodes are down (i.e. planned shutdown, server crash, etc) the client would still be able to connect to the cluster(s) when it restarted.

Note that client need this list of connect nodes **at the time of start up**, once communicated with the cluster it will maintain its own track of active/inactive cluster nodes.

I have in production one cluster of 3 nodes and all my clients have all nodes in the connect configuration, e.g.

```
http://my-node1:8091/pools,http://my-node2:8091/pools,http://my-node3:8091/pools
```

Regarding multiple clusters I'm not sure it will work with the same client instance unless a Couchbase client instance is smart enough to distinguish multiple clusters and keep track of its nodes health. Read on [Couchbase installation guide](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-2.5/cb-install/)

I found in documentation if you are using [Couchbase Moxi](http://docs.couchbase.com/moxi-manual-1.8/#command-line-configuration) it does support multiple clusters:

> Moxi also supports proxying to multiple clusters from a single moxi
>   instance, where this was originally designed and implemented for
>   software-as-a-service purposes. Use a semicolon (';') to specify and
>   delimit more than one cluster:

```
-z “LISTEN_PORT=[CLUSTER_CONFIG][;LISTEN_PORT2=[CLUSTER_CONFIG2][]]”
```